# How to remove and image from a page by src or title with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have some html with the following:

```
<img title="image1" src="../path/image1.jpg" />
<img title="image2" src="../path/image2.jpg" />
```

Is there a way to remove image1 only with jQuery?  And after checking if it exists (or do I care if it exists)?  I'm guessing I would need to match title or src.

I tried:

```
$('img').attr('title', 'image1').remove()
```

But .remove() is not available there.

Comment: This is extremely basic jQuery usage and is covered by the API docs. Please make an effort to use what's there first. http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery's [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

```
$('img[title="image1"]').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

you're better off working with css selectors

```
$('img[title=image1]').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are setting the title attribute of ALL img elements and then immediately removing them.

Give the img element an ID and remove it as follows.

> ```
> <img id="image1" title="image1" src="../path/image1.jpg" />
> ```

And then execute the following script.

```
$('#image1').remove();
```